# Spring Security Intercept-url pattern not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

My application can have below URLs:

```
/siteadmin/homepage/
/siteusers/customer/createCustomer
```

Below is my `spring-security.xml`:

```xml
<beans:beans> 
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/siteusers***" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="siteusers/home/*" access="hasRole('USER') OR hasRole('ADMIN')" /> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/siteadmin***" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />`enter code here`
        <form-login login-page="/siteusers/loginprocess/login" default-target-url="/siteusers/home/homepage"
            login-processing-url="/siteusers/loginprocess/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/siteusers/loginprocess/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/siteusers/loginprocess/login?logout" logout-url="/siteusers/loginprocess/logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="b" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="a" password="a" authorities="ROLE_USER" /><!-- This user can not access /admin url -->
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

If I logged in with user 'a' and hit URL `http://localhost:8080/siteadmin/homepage/` it is allowing user 'a' to view the page although his role is not `admin`. But when I try to hit `http://localhost:8080/siteadmin` then Spring Security is working fine ie. its showing access denied page.
I want to restrict `/admin/*` URLs for users who doesn't have `Admin` role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [AntPathMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html):

> The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:
>
> - `?` matches one character
> - `*` matches zero or more characters
> - `**` matches zero or more directories in a path
>
> Some examples:
>
> - `com/t?st.jsp` - matches `com/test.jsp` but also `com/tast.jsp` or `com/txst.jsp`
> - `com/*.jsp` - matches all `.jsp` files in the `com` directory
> - `com/**/test.jsp` - matches all `test.jsp` files underneath the `com` path
> - `org/springframework/**/*.jsp` - matches all `.jsp` files underneath the `org/springframework` path
> - `org/**/servlet/bla.jsp` - matches `org/springframework/servlet/bla.jsp` but  also `org/springframework/testing/servlet/bla.jsp` and `org/servlet/bla.jsp`

Your pattern `/siteadmin***`misses slashes. Use `/siteadmin/**`.

Comment: I want to support login.jsp, login.js and login.do, what pattern should I use for this case since there is not slash separating them. Three different patterns, one for each works but can it be done with just a single pattern as all of them start with the word login?