# Access with intercept-url pattern

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement Spring Security with XML and I used `intercept-url` tag for access. This is my code:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/frmWaterFilterReport/api**"
               access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','GUEST')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/frmWaterFilterReport/secure/api**"
               access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"/>
```

But the second tag doesn't work. User with role `GUEST` has access to these URLs:

```
/frmWaterFilterReport/secure/api**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429104/spring-security-intercept-url-pattern-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security Intercept-url pattern not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429104/spring-security-intercept-url-pattern-not-working)